# ¿Cómo recorrer una cadena en SQL?(ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito sacarle la información que se encuentra entre comillas a una cadena ("")

Ya pude sacar información de esta con:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CADENA,'"[^"]"')
```

Con eso estoy recuperando ya la primer cadena entre comillas, pero quisiera saber si pueden asesorarme en cómo recorrer la cadena para sacar las 2 que aún me falta, ya sea en la misma fila concatenadas o una fila para cada una.

La cuestión es que no puedo crear procedimientos o funciones para esto. Además la cadena no es dinámica ya que puede tener mas de una cadena entre comillas y tienen distinto nombre.
Entonces ¿Cómo podría hacerlo directamente en la consulta?

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Deberías usar los demás parámetros de la función **REGEXP_SUBSTR** para lograr lo que deseas, en este caso, el 3er parámetro es el que indica desde dónde comenzar la búsqueda y el 4to es el que indica qué número de ocurrencia del patrón que estás buscando te va a devolver la función.
En este caso, te está devolviendo siempre la primera ocurrencia porque no indicaste este parámetro.
Por lo tanto, podrías hacer algo así:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CADENA,'"[^"]"',1, 1) || REGEXP_SUBSTR(CADENA,'"[^"]"',1, 2) || REGEXP_SUBSTR(CADENA,'"[^"]"',1, 3)
```

Esto te devolvería las primeras 3 ocurrencias concatenadas del parámetro que estás buscando (texto entre paréntesis).